# Creating a temporary view in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

My company has support for jupyter notebooks running on Spark that can talk to data in S3.  The details of that aren't important outside of the fact that I'm trying to do a SQL like command to bring in data.  It looks something like this

```
df = spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (
   SELECT
      thing1,
      thing2
    FROM table1);""").toPandas()
```

However in doing so I get the following syntax error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input ';' expecting {<EOF>, 'ORDER', 'LIMIT', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 5, pos 16)

== SQL ==
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW my_view AS (
   SELECT
      thing1,
      thing2
    FROM table1);
----------------^^^
```

It's clear to me what it's complaining about but I don't get WHY it doesn't like that syntax, it seems to be pretty standard.  I have a subsequent block SQL block that I want to execute that will do a left join with that view from another table

**UPDATE**
One comment suggested removing the `;`.  However when doing that, I can't do any subsequent `SELECT` statements.  Here is an updated example for that case

```
df = spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (
   SELECT
      thing1,
      thing2
    FROM table1)

    SELECT
       view.thing1,
       view.thing2,
       table2.thing3
    FROM view
    LEFT JOIN table3
    ON
       table3.thing2 = view.thing2
    """).toPandas()
```

But this yields

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting {<EOF>, 'ORDER', 'LIMIT', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 7, pos 4)

== SQL ==
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (
   SELECT
      thing1,
      thing2
    FROM table1)

    SELECT
----^^^
       view.thing1,
       view.thing2,
       table2.thing3
    FROM view
    LEFT JOIN table3
    ON
       table3.thing2 = view.thing2
```

Comment: Remove semicolon ; not required in spark sql

Comment: @Srinivas I've tried that as well, but that still doesn't allow for subsequent statements.  Perhaps that can't be done in one SQL statement on spark SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `;` will fail with below `exception`

`spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (SELECT thing1, thing2 FROM table1);""")`

**Exception**

u"\nextraneous input ';' expecting (line 1, pos 52)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (SELECT thing1, thing2 FROM table1);
\n----------------------------------------------------^^^\n"

Removing `;` Query will work.

`spark.sql("""create temporary view view as (select * from vtable)""") # without ;`

**Note** : It's always good to split sql query into multiple parts else it's difficult to debug.

Change below query

```
df = spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (
   SELECT
      thing1,
      thing2
    FROM table1)

    SELECT
       view.thing1,
       view.thing2,
       table2.thing3
    FROM view
    LEFT JOIN table3
    ON
       table3.thing2 = view.thing2
    """).toPandas()
```

to

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view AS (SELECT thing1, thing2 FROM table1)""") 
df = spark.sql("""SELECT view.thing1, view.thing2, table2.thing3 FROM view LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.thing2 = view.thing2""").toPandas()
```